# Visual Studio 2013 doesn't stop on a code line at error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

In the previous versions of VS, if I have an error in my code and there was no exception handling - in debug mode - the debugger stops on the faulty code line, e.g. in case of an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

But now the debugger only stops in the `app.g.i.cs` file where I have an `UnhandledException` handler.

What should I set to get back the old behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

control, alt + E to bring up exceptions, then check Common Language Runtime Exceptions thrown column.  This will then break where the exception occurs rather than where it's handled.

Comment: Thanks for quick and useful response.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` in the Exceptions settings. *Debug > Windows > Exception settings.*

you can find more about it here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On debug mode, press Ctrl+E to show Exception tab. In Exception tab on debug mode, you'll see "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" check box. And click on it to make it checked. Run your application on debug mode. You'll see that the IDE will stop on error line. Take care!